# Retrieve items from a SharePoint All list using JavaScript Object Model (JSOM)

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

How do I get  list item ( 4 list )   using the javascript object model?
Relevant code as follows :

```
<script src="/JS/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveAllListProperties(), "sp.js"); });




function retrieveAllListProperties() {


var siteUrl="";
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web()
var oList = oWebsite.get_lists();
  var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
  var allItems = oList.getItems(query);

clientContext.load(allItems,'Include(Title, status)');

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

var listInfo = '';

var listEnumerator = allItems.getEnumerator();

while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
    listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_item('status') + '\n';
}
alert(listInfo);
}

  function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are not looping the oList object which holds all the SPLists. first load that and then do the oList.getItems()

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getAllLists,'sp.js');
    function getAllLists()
    {
        var result = []; 
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var lists = ctx.get_web().get_lists();
        ctx.load(lists,"Include(Id,Title)");

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(
          function() {

               lists.get_data().forEach(function(list){
                   var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
                   ctx.load(items,"Include(Id,FileRef)");
                   var listEntry = {
                     id: list.get_id().toString(),
                     title: list.get_title()
                   }
                   result.push({list: listEntry,
                                items: items}); 
               });
               ctx.executeQueryAsync(
               function() {
                   //transform listitem properties
                   result.forEach(function(item){

                       item.items = item.items.get_data().map(function(listItem){
                            return listItem.get_fieldValues(); 
                       });
                   }); 

                   console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
               },logError); 


          },logError);
     }
      function logError(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
    }
    </script>
```

Reference:

[Get all lists and list items in a SharePoint site with JSOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093356/get-all-lists-and-list-items-in-a-sharepoint-site-with-jsom#comment83307458_48125954)